# Java- Issue with Return Data's accuracy inside of a loop

Tags: java, class, infinite-loop

my previous questions have been taken care of. However I'm having an issue with the accuracy of data I'm pulling from another class.  I'm aware that currentScore.finalScore only updates when used. However, I have finalScore = currentScore.finalScore. The print line I have shows that it updates, but by seemingly random numbers and even when this number causes the while statement to become false, it continues infinitely.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 
       String buddyName;
       String userChoice;
       int maxScore = 10;      
       int minScore = 0;

       System.out.print("Nurse: The Patient's first name is ");
       buddyName = keyboard.nextLine();

       System.out.print("You: Let's see, I should (C)hange " + buddyName + "'s bandages," +
                       "(G)ive " + buddyName + " pain medication, " + 
                    "(A)dd antibiotics to " + buddyName + "'s I.V," +
                    " or (D)ischarge " + buddyName + " ");

      userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

      Buddy score = new Buddy(userChoice);
      BuddyScore currentScore = new BuddyScore(score);

      int finalScore;             
      do {
         System.out.print("You: Let's see, I should (C)hange " + buddyName + "'s"
                + " bandages, (G)ive " + buddyName + " pain medication, " + 
                    "(A)dd antibiotics to " + buddyName + "'s I.V," +
                    " or (D)ischarge " + buddyName + " ");

          userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
          score.setUserChoice(userChoice);
          finalScore = currentScore.getFinalScore();
          System.out.println(currentScore.getFinalScore());
          }while (currentScore.getFinalScore() < maxScore && currentScore.getFinalScore() >= minScore);

           System.out.println("Curren score: " + currentScore.getFinalScore());




        }

  }
```

Below is my class that handles the finalScore, and is the class I'm suspect of.

```
public class BuddyScore {
    private Buddy buddyScore;
    public int finalScore;


    public BuddyScore(Buddy buddyScore){
        this.buddyScore = buddyScore;
        this.finalScore = finalScore;
    }

    public void setFinalScore(int finalScore){
        this.finalScore = finalScore;
    }

    public int getFinalScore(){
      return finalScore += buddyScore.getBuddyScore();
    }    

}
```

Below is the class that handles the buddyScore that the finalScore pulls from.

```
public class Buddy {
    private String userChoice;
    public int buddyScore;  


    public Buddy(String userChoice){
        this.userChoice = userChoice;    
    }


    public void setUserChoice(String userChoice){
        this.userChoice = userChoice;
    }


    public String getUserChoice(){
       return userChoice;
    }


    public void setBuddyScore(int buddyScore){
        this.buddyScore = buddyScore;
    }



    public int getBuddyScore(){

      switch (userChoice){
        case "C":
            buddyScore = 1;
            break;
        case "G":
            buddyScore = -2;
            break;
        case "A":
            buddyScore = 3;
            break;
        case "D":
            buddyScore = 7;
            break;
        default:
            buddyScore = 0;
            break;
      };
     return buddyScore;

  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The side effect of your `getFinalScore` method is that it alters the `finalScore` with the return value of `getBuddyScore` before finally returning. As a result, each call to `getFinalScore` will increase the value. In your loop, I see you calling that method four times; if you step through the code, you should see four completely different values within the same iteration.

I am guessing you want to do this instead?

```
return finalScore + buddy.getBuddyScore();
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, I actually found the issue. I created a method to return just the finalValue. This allowed for the score to be returned with out also adding buddyScore.  Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

your while loop is wrong,
the operator should be && not ||

`while (currentScore.getFinalScore() < maxScore && currentScore.getFinalScore() >= minScore);`

causes this to always be true with a value of 0 and above.

Comment: I'm not sure how I overlooked something so simple, I appreciate you pointing it out to me. However, I'm still unsure as to why the finalScore is increasing by what looks to be a multiplication of the user inputs value.